# Javascript Element type "n.length

Tags: javascript, newrelic

I wanted to use a script to monitor the performance of my web application.
I had the javaScript code snippet generated from the new Relic site and added it to my app but when I run the app, I get the following error:

```
Error Parsing /index.xhtml: Error Traced[line: 23] Element type "n.length" must be followed by either attribute specifications, ">" or "/>".
```

Here is the code that was generated for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.NREUM||(NREUM={}),__nr_require=function(t,e,n){function r(n)
{
  if(!e[n]){var o=e[n]={exports:{}};t[n[0].call(o.exports,function(e)
{
   var o=t[n][1][e];return r(o?o:e)},o,o.exports)}
 return e[n].exports
   }
 if("function"==typeof__nr_require)return __nr_require;
 for(var o=0;o<n.length;o++)r(n[o]);
 return r
}({
    QJf3ax:[function(t,e)
 {
  function n(t){function e(e,n,a)
 {
   t&&t(e,n,a),a||(a={});for(var c=s(e),f=c.length,u=i(a,o,r),d=0; 
 f>d;d++)c[d].apply(u,n); return u}
 function a(t,e){f[t]=s(t).concat(e)}
 function s(t){
 return f[t]||[]}function c(){
 return n(e)}var 
 f={};return{on:a,emit:e,create:c,listeners:s,_events:f}
  }
 function r(){
  return{
   }
    }var o="nr@context",i=t("gos");e.exports=n()},
 {
   gos:"7eSDFh"}],ee:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("QJf3ax")},{}],3:
[function(t){function e(t)
{try{i.console&&console.log(t)}catch(e){}}var n,r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i{
 }; try{
        n=localStorage.getItem("__nr_flags").split(","),console&&"
  function"==typeof console.log&&(i.console=!0,-1!==n.indexOf("dev")&&   (i.dev=!0),-1!==n.indexOf("nr_dev")&&(i.nrDev=!0))}catch(a){
 }i.nrDev&&r.on("internal-error",
function(t){e(t.stack)}),i.dev&&r.on("fn-err",function(t,n,r){e(r.stack)}),
i.dev&&(e("NR AGENT IN DEVELOPMENT MODE"),e("flags: "+o(i,function(t)
{
 return t}).join(", ")))},{1:22,ee:"QJf3ax"}],4:[function(t)
{
 function e(t,e,n,i,s){try{c?c-=1:r("err",[s||new UncaughtException(t,e,n)])}
catch(f){
     try{r("ierr",[f,(new Date).getTime(),!0])}
catch(u){}}return"function"==typeof a?a.apply(this,o(arguments)):!1}
   function UncaughtException(t,e,n){this.message=t||"Uncaught error with no additional information",this.sourceURL=e,this.line=n}
function n(t){r("err",[t,(new Date).getTime()])}var r=t("handle"),o=t(6),i=t("ee"),a=window.onerror,s=!1,c=0;t("loader").features.err=!0,t(5),window.onerror=e;
try{throw new Error}
catch(f){"stack"in f&&(t(1),t(2),"addEventListener"in window&&t(3),window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)&&t(4),s=!0)}i.on("fn-start",
 function(){s&&(c+=1)}),i.on("fn-err",
 function(t,e,r){s&&(this.thrown=!0,n(r))}),i.on("fn-end",function(){s&&!this.thrown&&c>0&&(c-=1)}),i.on("internal-error",
  function(t){r("ierr",[t,(new Date).getTime(),!0])})},{1:9,2:8,3:6,4:10,5:3,6:23,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],5:[function(t){
 function e(){}
  if
 (window.performance&&window.performance.timing&&window.performance.getEntriesByType){
 var n=t("ee"),r=t("handle"),o=t(1),i=t(2);t("loader").features.stn=!0,t(3),n.on("fn-start",function(t){var e=t[0];e instanceof Event&&(this.bstStart=Date.now())}),n.on("fn-end",
  function(t,e){
  var n=t[0];n instanceof Event&&r("bst",[n,e,this.bstStart,Date.now()])}),o.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n)
  {this.bstStart=Date.now(),this.bstType=n}),o.on("fn-end",
   function(t,e)
   {r("bstTimer",[e,this.bstStart,Date.now(),this.bstType])}),i.on("fn-start",
     function(){this.bstStart=Date.now()}),i.on("fn-end",
    function(t,e){r("bstTimer",[e,this.bstStart,Date.now(),"requestAnimationFrame"])}),n.on("pushState-start",  function()this.time=Date.now(),this.startPath=location.pathname+location.hash}),n.on("pushState-end",
 function(){r("bstHist",[location.pathname+location.hash,this.startPath,this.time])}),"addEventListener"in window.performance&&(window.performance.addEventListener("webkitresourcetimingbufferfull",function(){r("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.webkitClearResourceTimings()},!1),window.performance.addEventListener("resourcetimingbufferfull",
   function(){r("bstResource",[window.performance.getEntriesByType("resource")]),window.performance.clearResourceTimings()},!1)),document.addEventListener("scroll",e,!1),document.addEventListener("keypress",e,!1),document.addEventListener("click",e,!1)}},{1:9,2:8,3:7,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],6:[
   function(t,e){
    function n(t){i.inPlace(t,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",r)}
function r(t){return t[1]}var o=t("ee").create(),i=t(1)(o),a=t("gos");if(e.exports=o,n(window),"getPrototypeOf"in Object){
  for(var s=document;s&&!s.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)s=Object.getPrototypeOf(s);s&&n(s);for(var c=XMLHttpRequest.prototype;c&&!c.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener");)c=Object.getPrototypeOf(c);c&&n(c)}
   else XMLHttpRequest.prototype.hasOwnProperty("addEventListener")&&n(XMLHttpRequest.prototype);o.on("addEventListener-start",
   function(t){if(t[1]){var e=t[1];"function"==typeof e?this.wrapped=t[1]=a(e,"nr@wrapped",
   function(){
    return i(e,"fn-",null,e.name||"anonymous")}):"function"==typeof e.handleEvent&&i.inPlace(e,["handleEvent"],"fn-")}}),o.on("removeEventListener-start",function(t){var e=this.wrapped;e&&(t[1]=e)})},{1:24,ee:"QJf3ax",gos:"7eSDFh"}],7:[function(t,e){var n=t("ee").create(),r=t(1)(n);e.exports=n,r.inPlace(window.history,["pushState"],"-")},{1:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],8:[function(t,e){var n=t("ee").create(),r=t(1)(n);e.exports=n,r.inPlace(window,["requestAnimationFrame","mozRequestAnimationFrame","webkitRequestAnimationFrame","msRequestAnimationFrame"],"raf-"),n.on("raf-start",function(t){t[0]=r(t[0],"fn-")})},{1:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],9:[function(t,e)
{function n(t,e,n){t[0]=o(t[0],"fn-",null,n)}var r=t("ee").create(),o=t(1)(r);e.exports=r,o.inPlace(window,["setTimeout","setInterval","setImmediate"],"setTimer-"),r.on("setTimer-start",n)},{1:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],10:[function(t,e)
{function n(){f.inPlace(this,p,"fn-")}function r(t,e){f.inPlace(e,["onreadystatechange"],"fn-")}
  function o(t,e){return e}
   function i(t,e){for(var n in t)e[n]=t[n];return e}var a=t("ee").create(),s=t(1),c=t(2),f=c(a),u=c(s),d=window.XMLHttpRequest,p=["onload","onerror","onabort","onloadstart","onloadend","onprogress","ontimeout"];e.exports=a,window.XMLHttpRequest=function(t){var e=new d(t);try{a.emit("new-xhr",[],e),u.inPlace(e,["addEventListener","removeEventListener"],"-",o),e.addEventListener("readystatechange",n,!1)}
  catch(r){try{a.emit("internal-error",[r])}catch(i){}}
return e},i(d,XMLHttpRequest),XMLHttpRequest.prototype=d.prototype,f.inPlace(XMLHttpRequest.prototype,["open","send"],"-xhr-",o),a.on("send-xhr-start",r),a.on("open-xhr-start",r)},{1:6,2:24,ee:"QJf3ax"}],11:[function(t)
{function e(t)
 {var e=this.params,r=this.metrics;if(!this.ended){this.ended=!0;for(var i=0;c>i;i++)t.removeEventListener(s[i],this.listener,!1);if(!e.aborted){if(r.duration=(new Date).getTime()-this.startTime,4===t.readyState){e.status=t.status;var a=t.responseType,f="arraybuffer"===a||"blob"===a||"json"===a?t.response:t.responseText,u=n(f);
   if(u&&(r.rxSize=u),this.sameOrigin){var d=t.getResponseHeader("X-NewRelic-App-Data");d&&(e.cat=d.split(", ").pop())}}
    else e.status=0;r.cbTime=this.cbTime,o("xhr",[e,r,this.startTime])}}}function n(t)
{if("string"==typeof t&&t.length)return t.length;
if("object"!=typeof t)return void 0;if("undefined"!=typeof ArrayBuffer&&t instanceof ArrayBuffer&&t.byteLength)return t.byteLength;
if("undefined"!=typeof Blob&&t instanceof Blob&&t.size)return t.size;
if("undefined"!=typeof FormData&&t instanceof FormData)return void 0;try{return JSON.stringify(t).length}catch(e){return void 0}}function r(t,e){var n=i(e),r=t.params;r.host=n.hostname+":"+n.port,r.pathname=n.pathname,t.sameOrigin=n.sameOrigin}if(window.XMLHttpRequest&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype&&XMLHttpRequest.prototype.addEventListener&&!/CriOS/.test(navigator.userAgent)){t("loader").features.xhr=!0;var o=t("handle"),i=t(2),a=t("ee"),s=["load","error","abort","timeout"],c=s.length,f=t(1);t(4),t(3),a.on("new-xhr",function(){this.totalCbs=0,this.called=0,this.cbTime=0,this.end=e,this.ended=!1,this.xhrGuids={}}),a.on("open-xhr-start",
 function(t){this.params={method:t[0]},r(this,t[1]),this.metrics={}}),a.on("open-xhr-end",
   function(t,e){"loader_config"in NREUM&&"xpid"in NREUM.loader_config&&this.sameOrigin&&e.setRequestHeader("X-NewRelic-ID",NREUM.loader_config.xpid)}),a.on("send-xhr-start",
   function(t,e){var r=this.metrics,o=t[0],i=this;if(r&&o){var f=n(o);f&&(r.txSize=f)}this.startTime=(new Date).getTime(),this.listener=function(t)
{try{"abort"===t.type&&(i.params.aborted=!0),("load"!==t.type||i.called===i.totalCbs&&(i.onloadCalled||"function"!=typeof e.onload))&&i.end(e)}
  catch(n){
   try{a.emit("internal-error",[n])}
   catch(r){}}};
   for(var u=0;c>u;u++)e.addEventListener(s[u],this.listener,!1)}),a.on("xhr-cb-time",
    function(t,e,n){this.cbTime+=t,e?this.onloadCalled=!0:this.called+=1,this.called!==this.totalCbs||!this.onloadCalled&&"function"==typeof n.onload||this.end(n)}),a.on("xhr-load-added",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&!this.xhrGuids[n]&&(this.xhrGuids[n]=!0,this.totalCbs+=1)}),a.on("xhr-load-removed",function(t,e){var n=""+f(t)+!!e;this.xhrGuids&&this.xhrGuids[n]&&(delete this.xhrGuids[n],this.totalCbs-=1)}),a.on("addEventListener-end",
   function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-added",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("removeEventListener-end",
    function(t,e){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&"load"===t[0]&&a.emit("xhr-load-removed",[t[1],t[2]],e)}),a.on("fn-start",function(t,e,n){e instanceof XMLHttpRequest&&("onload"===n&&(this.onload=!0),("load"===(t[0]&&t[0].type)||this.onload)&&(this.xhrCbStart=(new Date).getTime()))}),a.on("fn-end",
  function(t,e){this.xhrCbStart&&a.emit("xhr-cb-time",[(new Date).getTime()-this.xhrCbStart,this.onload,e],e)})}},{1:"XL7HBI",2:12,3:10,4:6,ee:"QJf3ax",handle:"D5DuLP",loader:"G9z0Bl"}],12:[function(t,e){e.exports=function(t)
  {var e=document.createElement("a"),n=window.location,r={};e.href=t,r.port=e.port;var o=e.href.split("://");
return!r.port&&o[1]&&(r.port=o[1].split("/")[0].split("@").pop().split(":")[1]),r.port&&"0"!==r.port||(r.port="https"===o[0]?"443":"80"),r.hostname=e.hostname||n.hostname,r.pathname=e.pathname,r.protocol=o[0],"/"!==r.pathname.charAt(0)&&(r.pathname="/"+r.pathname),r.sameOrigin=!e.hostname||e.hostname===document.domain&&e.port===n.port&&e.protocol===n.protocol,r}},{}],13:[function(t,e){function n(t){
  return function(){r(t,[(new Date).getTime()].concat(i(arguments)))}}var r=t("handle"),o=t(1),i=t(2);"undefined"==typeof window.newrelic&&(newrelic=window.NREUM);var a=["setPageViewName","addPageAction","setCustomAttribute","finished","addToTrace","inlineHit","noticeError"];
o(a,
   function(t,e){window.NREUM[e]=n("api-"+e)}),e.exports=window.NREUM},{1:22,2:23,handle:"D5DuLP"}],gos:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("7eSDFh")},{}],"7eSDFh":[
    function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){if(r.call(t,e))return t[e];
var o=n();
if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)
   try{return Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:o,writable:!0,enumerable:!1}),o}
   catch(i){}return t[e]=o,o}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=n},{}],D5DuLP:[
    function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){return r.listeners(t).length?r.emit(t,e,n):void(r.q&&(r.q[t]||(r.q[t]=[]),r.q[t].push(e)))}var r=t("ee").create();e.exports=n,n.ee=r,r.q={}},{ee:"QJf3ax"}],handle:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("D5DuLP")},{}],XL7HBI:[function(t,e){function n(t){var e=typeof t;
return!t||"object"!==e&&"function"!==e?-1:t===window?0:i(t,o,function()
 {return r++})}
  var r=1,o="nr@id",i=t("gos");
e.exports=n},{gos:"7eSDFh"}],id:[function(t,e)
  {e.exports=t("XL7HBI")},{}],G9z0Bl:[function(t,e){function n(){var t=p.info=NREUM.info,e=f.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
if(t&&t.licenseKey&&t.applicationID&&e){s(d,
  function(e,n){e in t||(t[e]=n)});
var n="https"===u.split(":")[0]||t.sslForHttp;p.proto=n?"https://":"http://",a("mark",["onload",i()]);var r=f.createElement("script"); 
r.src=p.proto+t.agent,e.parentNode.insertBefore(r,e)}}
  function r(){"complete"===f.readyState&&o()}
   function o(){a("mark",["domContent",i()])}function i(){return(new Date).getTime()}var a=t("handle"),s=t(1),c=window,f=c.document;t(2);
var u=(""+location).split("?")[0],d={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-686.min.js"},p=e.exports={offset:i(),origin:u,features:{}};
f.addEventListener?(f.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",o,!1),c.addEventListener("load",n,!1)):(f.attachEvent("onreadystatechange",r),c.attachEvent("onload",n)),a("mark",["firstbyte",i()])},{1:22,2:13,handle:"D5DuLP"}],loader:[function(t,e){e.exports=t("G9z0Bl")},{}],22:[
   function(t,e){function n(t,e){var n=[],o="",i=0;for(o in t)r.call(t,o)&&(n[i]=e(o,t[o]),i+=1);
return n}var r=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;
e.exports=n},{}],23:[function(t,e){function n(t,e,n){e||(e=0),"undefined"==typeof n&&(n=t?t.length:0);
for(var r=-1,o=n-e||0,i=Array(0>o?0:o);++r<o;)i[r]=t[e+r];
return i}e.exports=n},{}],24:[
  function(t,e){
  function n(t){return!(t&&"function"==typeof t&&t.apply&&!t[i])}var r=t("ee"),o=t(1),i="nr@wrapper",a=Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty;e.exports=function(t){
 function e(t,e,r,a){function nrWrapper(){var n,i,s,f;try{i=this,n=o(arguments),s=r&&r(n,i)||{}}catch(d){u([d,"",[n,i,a],s])}c(e+"start",[n,i,a],s);
try{return f=t.apply(i,n)}catch(p){throw c(e+"err",[n,i,p],s),p}finally{c(e+"end",[n,i,f],s)}}
  return n(t)?t:(e||(e=""),nrWrapper[i]=!0,f(t,nrWrapper),nrWrapper)}
  function s(t,r,o,i){o||(o="");var a,s,c,f="-"===o.charAt(0);for(c=0;c<r.length;c++)s=r[c],a=t[s],n(a)||(t[s]=e(a,f?s+o:o,i,s))}
  function c(e,n,r){try{t.emit(e,n,r)}
   catch(o){u([o,e,n,r])}}
   function f(t,e){
    if(Object.defineProperty&&Object.keys)
     try{var n=Object.keys(t);
     return n.forEach(function(n){Object.defineProperty(e,n,{get:function(){
     return t[n]},set:function(e){
      return t[n]=e,e}})}),e}
      catch(r){u([r])}for(var o in t)a.call(t,o)&&(e[o]=t[o]);
      return e}function u(e){
      try{t.emit("internal-error",e)}
      catch(n){}}
      return t||(t=r),e.inPlace=s,e.flag=i,e}},
      {1:23,ee:"QJf3ax"}]},{},["G9z0Bl",4,11,5]);
 NREUM.info={beacon:"bam.nr-data.net",errorBeacon:"bam.nr-data.net",licenseKey:"3e08bdef4c",applicationID:"8299084",sa:1,agent:"js-agent.newrelic.com/nr-686.min.js"}
</script>
```

The code is meant to enable me to monitor the availability and performance of my web app via the new Relic apm.

Comment: Java is a different language from Javascript.  Please do not use the Java tag unless your question is related to Java somehow.

Comment: Do you have a question? No one is going to debug minified code for you. Voting to close, based on the fact that there isn't a question that can be answered, and that OP barely knows which language they are using, which is a big red flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your XHTML parser is reading `<n.length` as an XHTML tag, as part of the XHTML script, probably because of the strict parsing of XHTML. I would recommend transferring this script to a separate JavaScript file (with a .js file extension) in the same directory, and changing your script tag to

`<script type="text/javascript" src="filename.js">`

Comment: Although this is hard to read code, the error is clear: it is the "<n.length" part, which the parser is picking up as XHTML code — **very** clear given the error message. Clearly, the OP wants to know why he is getting error. Yes, no question and unclear code, but an obvious and easily solvable issue if you take a few seconds to look at the error message.

Comment: That being said, be sure to know the difference between Java and JavaScript.

Comment: A simple solution may be to use an HTML doctype instead?

Comment: Good idea. Probably under <html> and <head> tags too.

Comment: Thanks @Dodo that worked.

Comment: @RobG, I had tried  using the HTML doctype  before posting the question but it didn't work

Comment: It's probably good practice to include all of these suggestions; it is after all XHTML.